# Does the Jetty Maven Plugin 8.0.0.M3 support all of Servlet 3?

Tags: jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, servlet-3.0

I have the following in my web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
    <secure>true</secure>
  </cookie-config>
  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

However, according to OWASP's Zed Attack Proxy (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project), cookies are still being set by Spring Security w/o the httpOnly or secure flags.

If I deploy the same app in Tomcat 7, it appears to honor these settings from web.xml.

Comment: Figured it out - I had the elements in the wrong order. No errors from Tomcat or Jetty, but GlassFish complained and helped me find the solution.

Comment: I can't get Jetty 8 to respect the tracking-mode though (using the Maven plugin org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.4.v20120524) - even though request.getServletContext().getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes() is just COOKIE, I still get the jsessionid in the URL if I disable cookies.  Did you get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** Put the elements in the correct order:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```